# Cucumber claims its support files are broken?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

Using cucumber for ruby on rails, I ran a test that failed for a silly reason (I'd made a typo). I fixed the problem, and suddenly, Cucumber won't run anymore. I didn't change any of the files it refers to:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.1.8/lib/cucumber/js_support/js_dsl.js:3: 
syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting keyword_then or ';' or '\n'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.1.8/lib/cucumber/js_support/js_dsl.js:6: syntax error, unexpected keyword_else, expecting '}'
    else {
        ^
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.1.8/lib/cucumber/js_support/js_dsl.js:7: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting tASSOC
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-

1.1.8/lib/cucumber/js_support/js_dsl.js:13: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting $end (SyntaxError)
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in `load'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in `block in load'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in `load'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.1.8/lib/cucumber/js_support/js_language.rb:114:in `initialize'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.1.8/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:74:in `new'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.1.8/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:74:in `load_programming_language'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.1.8/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:185:in `programming_language_for'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.1.8/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:169:in `load_file'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.1.8/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:83:in `block in load_files!'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.1.8/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:82:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.1.8/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:82:in `load_files!'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.1.8/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:175:in `load_step_definitions'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.1.8/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:40:in `run!'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.1.8/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:43:in `execute!'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.1.8/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:20:in `execute'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.1.8/bin/cucumber:14:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/cucumber:19:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/cucumber:19:in `<main>'
```

Obviously something has gone terribly terribly wrong. My question is simply, how do I go about fixing this? Is this a known bug? Can/should I re-install cucumber? The whole stack? I have very little experience with Rails and Cucumber, and the obvious solutions are failing me (the file it complains about is fine, actually fairly readable, nothing odd about it; running it again reveals it wasn't just a fluke; breaking the feature I fixed changes nothing).

Lines 3-7 of js_dsl are:

```
 if (func == null) {
      jsLanguage.execute_step_definition(regexp);
    }
    else {
      jsLanguage.add_step_definition(regexp, func);
    }
  },
```

So I checked the step definition file and that also looks fine. Usually a step definition being wrong gives an error message, not a complete failure like this.

Comment: could you mark the best answer or update ur question with the solution you came up with ?? cuz it seems that none of the answers are helpfujl

Comment: @HadyElsahar I did list my solution below, but it's not a good one and I still don't understand what's wrong. You're exactly right, though, none of the answers are helpful, which is why I didn't accept one.

Answer (score 3):

I don't even...

My classmates discovered the problem [here](https://www.coursera.org/saas/forum/thread?thread_id=1811) and the solution [here](https://www.coursera.org/saas/forum/thread?thread_id=1821)

Apparently something called "theRubyRacer" which was part of the image I was told to use is now "obsolete", which apparently means "breaks cucumber despite it working fine ten minutes ago". Somehow, "simplecov" is involved, meaning I now have no idea how I'm supposed to get the coverage figures required for the assignment but I don't care anymore because I'm frusturated and confused and it works now. This just started today, so I'm thinking something somewhere contacted a server someplace that told it the gem was obsolete and thus refused to use it?

If anyone has further information, please do let me know.

---

Since apparently those links are walled off, the problem was:

> So I have identified the problem:
>
> The coverage folder.
>
> I can run and pass my cucumber and rspec tests without any sort of problem if I don't put require 'simplecov' SimpleCov.start 'rails' in the top of env.rb.
>
> All my steps are green, but If I add these two lines, I got the error above. If I delete de /coverage folder, I can run once the test, but the next time the error is reproduced again.
>
> Any help please?

and then the solution mentioned was

> Comment this line out of Gemfile and run bundle install again:
>
> `# gem 'therubyracer'`
>
> This is now obsolete. See:
>
> http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3x-asset-pipeline-cedar#therubyracer
>
> Which says:
>
> If you were previously using therubyracer or therubyracer-heroku, these gems are no longer
>   required and strongly discouraged as these gems use a very large amount of memory.

Comment: We can't see those links you provided. And your explanation of the problem (which I also just ran into) seems implausible, to say the least. More info?

Comment: @MarnenLaibow-Koser I'm as lost as you are. That was the first exposure I'd had to Ruby and Rails and it was a huge disaster where we students had to solve the issue ourselves; I have no idea what the real problem was, only that removing theRubyRacer made the error go away. I'll see if I can't fetch out the link contents though, I had thought the forums were public.

Comment: I don't believe that this is a therubyracer issue, at least not entirely. I just had it happen more or less under the circumstances in http://stackoverflow.com/a/10020625/109011 , so I think what was going on is that features in a nonexistent directory were being specified, and that this was somehow confusing Cucumber into executing JavaScript as if it were Ruby.

Comment: Also, as this is your introduction to Ruby and Rails, let me assure you that this is not typical. Virtually everything works together very nicely, or gives nice clear errors.

Comment: @MarnenLaibow-Koser Honestly I think it was a poorly-taught course. This sort of thing didn't happen much, but when it did, the instructors were nowhere to be found.

Answer (score 2):

For clarity: bec == bundle exec cucumber

It forces the exec'd directive to use the gems as specified in Gemfile.lock

These two work:
bec && bec **features**/foo.feature

This one doesn't, complaining about syntax errors in js_dsl.js:
bec foo.feature

cucumber-1.1.9 (and very likely other versions too) assumes features/

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same syntax error from the same bit of correctly syntaxed javascript.

It might seem completely unrelated, but if you have

```
Feature: xyz

  @some-tag
  Scenario Outline
  When I "<foo>"

  @some-tag # TRY REMOVING THIS LINE
  Examples: 
  |foo|
  |bar|
```

then it caused that error in my case. Try removing the second tag. Tags are for scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue, and realized I was just being stupid.
I was doing:

```
bundle exec cucumber features/a_switch_store_navigation.feature -tags @foo
```

instead of:

```
bundle exec cucumber features/a_switch_store_navigation.feature --tags @foo
```

( `--tags` double dash )

Answer (score 0):

Are you coding an Engine? Because I was, when ran into exactly the same issue. I traced it down to Cucumber trying to load my .js files from app/assets (thinking they are features or parts thereof), by using wrong paths (in debugger it was recursively loading all files from project home, i.e. ".").

I think this happens because Cucumber expects features to be present in the engine folder, not dummy. So by moving features folder to the Engine folder, I've managed to fix it and Cucumber runs now. When doing so, I had to make some changes to env.rb, which are described under "Cucumber" section in this blog: http://blog.crowdint.com/2012/03/20/mountable-rails-engines.html

Possibly there is a way to configure Cucumber to pick up features from the dummy folder, but I haven't explored it.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error also , the problem i had was there were two ./coverage folders . I ran 'find . -iname coverage ' and deleted the coverage folder that was not required.

Answer (score 0):

I was testing a file upload feature and was using a test Javascript and CSS file to upload in the tests using Rack::Test::UploadedFile. When I renamed the JS and CSS from the .js/.css extensions to .js.test/.css.test extensions, this error went away.